# How can I display XML with whitespace formatting?  

Tags: php, xml, formatting, simplexml, whitespace

I have a web page that builds an XML from an existing XML applying changes.  I want to output the new XML file in a `textarea` as a preview.  It displays any nodes that were present in the original XML with the proper whitespaces/formatting (indents and linebreaks) that the original XML had just fine, but any new nodes are all displayed on one line with no indents.  Example:

```
<original parent node>
    <original child>value</original child>
</original parent node>
<original parent node>
    <new child>value</new child><new child>value</new child><new child>value</new child><new child>value</new child><new child>value</new child><new child>value</new child>
</original parent node>
```

Here is the code that writes and reads back in the XML:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
file_put_contents($file, $dom->saveXML());
echo "<textarea cols='100' rows='40'>".file_get_contents($file)."</textarea>";
```

I'm also using SimpleXML to manipulate the XMLS.  How can I get the proper whitespacing to display for the new nodes?

Comment: Wow. loadXML/asXML, file_put_contents/file_get_contents... What's that supposed to be good for? Related: What is `$xml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that `formatOutput` only works when `preserveWhiteSpace` is disabled:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: guys I'm stuck on 4th line as it's giving me an error: Notice: Undefined variable: xml in C:\wamp\www\3ace\index.php on line 88

Answer (score 1):

Add this, it works for me.

```
echo '<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>';
echo "<br/> <pre class=\"prettyprint\" >". htmlentities($dom->saveXML($dom->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild))."</pre>";
```

You can delete `$dom->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "<textarea cols='100' rows='40'>".htmlspecialchars($xml->asXML())."</textarea>";
```